# mysql : delete query doesn't work with a subquery

Tags: mysql

This query execution never ends.

```
delete from commande where bl in (
    select noBl from (
        select distinct noBl,num_commande from T_VENTE) s
    group by noBl
    having count(*)>2
);
```

I don't understand because the subquery

```
select noBl from (
        select distinct noBl,num_commande from T_VENTE) s
    group by noBl
    having count(*)>2
```

takes one second to achieve.

Column bl is indexed in table commande.

If someone has an idea...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use another level of subquery :
check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause/45498#45498)

```
delete from commande where bl in (
    select noBl from (
        select noBl from (
            select distinct noBl,num_commande from T_VENTE) s
        group by noBl
        having count(*)>2
    ) as tmp
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are achieve.You need to give detailed information.
You need a conditional statement for delete is something like this.

```
DELETE FROM customer1 WHERE agent_code=ANY(SELECT agent_code FROM agents WHERE working_area='London');
```

**How its work**

first get records from agent_code from agents table and then result are used to perform a delete operation.

Comment: the subquery gives a list of ids(noBl). I need to delete from table commande records that have an id contained in the list of ids of the subquery.

Comment: you need to create procedure